# Creating shareable media react-native

Tags: react-native, posts, social-media

I'm trying to create a react-native app, from which the users will be able to create shareable 'posts'. I want these posts to be shareable by link so other users can interact with them. Does anybody know how this could be done?

Comment: will that media can be updated by any user?

Comment: Your question can be split into multiple parts. Are you asking how to generate such posts or how to share them? To share content from within your app take a look at [deep links](https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking).

Comment: @sushrut619 I didnt split my question because I wasn't sure whether these two questions depend on each other. I want to be able to create posts for the purpose of sharing on external platform's.